# How to delete/reset an app from iOS 13 with XCTest?

Tags: xcode, xctest, ios13, xcode11, xcuitest

Recently I started testing an iOS app using XCTest but I found some difficulties, the main difficulty was deleting or resetting the app content in each test class.

I'm currently using XCode 11 and trying to delete/reset an app from iOS 13 for each test class, I've already tried:

- Delete app through springboard
- Delete app by going to the app settings

This step is really important in my tests because in each test I need to create a profile and log in, so in the next test I need to have the app just installed from scratch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to press the app icon a little longer than in previous iOS versions.

```
    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    func deleteMyApp() {
        XCUIApplication().terminate()

        let icon = springboard.icons["YourAppName"]
        if icon.exists {
            let iconFrame = icon.frame
            let springboardFrame = springboard.frame
            icon.press(forDuration: 5)

            // Tap the little "X" button at approximately where it is. The X is not exposed directly
            springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: (iconFrame.minX + 3) / springboardFrame.maxX, dy: (iconFrame.minY + 3) / springboardFrame.maxY)).tap()

            springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete"].tap()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for all iOS versions. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Good luck!

Comment: The app icon is not on the first screen, seems we need firstly swipe left?

Comment: this is not working in iOS 16 real device.

Answer (score 8):

## iOS 14

The working solution for `iOS 14`

```
import XCTest

let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

func deleteMyApp() {
    XCUIApplication().terminate()

    let bundleDisplayName = "MyApp"

    let icon = springboard.icons[bundleDisplayName]
    if icon.exists {
        icon.press(forDuration: 1)

        let buttonRemoveApp = springboard.buttons["Remove App"]
        if buttonRemoveApp.waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
            buttonRemoveApp.tap()
        } else {
            XCTFail("Button \"Remove App\" not found")
        }

        let buttonDeleteApp = springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete App"]
        if buttonDeleteApp.waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
            buttonDeleteApp.tap()
        }
        else {
            XCTFail("Button \"Delete App\" not found")
        }

        let buttonDelete = springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete"]
        if buttonDelete.waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
            buttonDelete.tap()
        }
        else {
            XCTFail("Button \"Delete\" not found")
        }
    }
}

class HomeUITests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testExample() throws {
        deleteMyApp()

        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

    func testLaunchPerformance() throws {
        if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *) {
            // This measures how long it takes to launch your application.
            measure(metrics: [XCTApplicationLaunchMetric()]) {
                XCUIApplication().launch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated Roman's answer to support iOS 13 on **iPad**.

By inserting `otherElements["Home screen icons"]`, the code works both of iPhone and iPad.

```
class Springboard {

    static let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    class func deleteMyApp() {
        XCUIApplication().terminate()

         // Insert otherElements["Home screen icons"] here
        let icon = springboard.otherElements["Home screen icons"].icons["Workoutimer"]
        if icon.exists {
            let iconFrame = icon.frame
            let springboardFrame = springboard.frame
            icon.press(forDuration: 5)

            // Tap the little "X" button at approximately where it is. The X is not exposed directly
            springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: (iconFrame.minX + 3) / springboardFrame.maxX, dy: (iconFrame.minY + 3) / springboardFrame.maxY)).tap()

            springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete"].tap()
            
            XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
        }
    }
 }
```

#### Misc.

On iPad, "recent launched app" will be added to the right side of the Dock. This iPad specific behavior leads XCUITest finds two elements if you search icons only by its identifier.

[Your app will be added here, too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZHTc.png)

To handle that, specify `otherElements["Home screen icons"]` and it excludes elements of the "Dock".

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Springboard {

    static let springboardApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    static let appName = "appName"

    static func deleteApp() {
        XCUIApplication().terminate()

        let icon = springboardApp.icons[appName]
        if icon.exists {
            icon.press(forDuration: 3)
            icon.buttons["DeleteButton"].tap()

            springboardApp.alerts.buttons["Delete"].tap()
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this via springboard same as you uninstall build by yourself.
Here is the class with deleteApp function which will uninstall build at anytime you need.

```
 class Springboard {
    
    static let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    
    class func deleteApp () {
        //terminate app and activate Springboard
        XCUIApplication().terminate()
        springboard.activate()
        
        //tap on app icon
        let appIcon = springboard.icons.matching(identifier: "App Display Name").firstMatch
        
        if appIcon.exists {
            
        appIcon.press(forDuration: 2.0)
            
           //Access first alert button (Remove App)
        let _ = springboard.alerts.buttons["Remove App"].waitForExistence(timeout: 1.0)
        springboard.buttons["Remove App"].tap()
        
        //Access second alert button (Delete App)
        let _ = springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete App"].waitForExistence(timeout: 1.0)
        springboard.buttons["Delete App"].tap()
        
        //Access second alert button (Delete)
        let _ = springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete"].waitForExistence(timeout: 1.0)
        springboard.buttons["Delete"].tap()

        }
    }
}
```

Usgae:

```
 func test_YourTestName() {
    Springboard.deleteApp()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty solution for iOS 14:

```
let appName = "You app name as it appears on the home screen"

// Put the app in the background
XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)

let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
if springboard.icons[appName].waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
    springboard.icons[appName].press(forDuration: 1.5);
}

if springboard.collectionViews.buttons["Remove App"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
    springboard.collectionViews.buttons["Remove App"].tap()
}

if springboard.alerts["Remove “\(appName)”?"].scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Delete App"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
    springboard.alerts["Remove “\(appName)”?"].scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Delete App"].tap()
}

if springboard.alerts["Delete “\(appName)”?"].scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Delete"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
    springboard.alerts["Delete “\(appName)”?"].scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Delete"].tap()
}
```

Comment: After pressing home button, the device goes to first screen. However, the testing app is on second screen, `springboard.icons[appName]` would be unhittable, which means cannot be pressed.

Answer (score -1):

**iOS 14 and below**

```
func deleteMyApp() {
XCUIApplication().terminate()

let bundleDisplayName = "App Name"

XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)

let icon = springboard.icons[bundleDisplayName]

if icon.waitForExistence(timeout: 5) {
    
    XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)

    
    let value = springboard.pageIndicators.element(boundBy: 0).value as? String
    
    let f = value!.last?.wholeNumberValue
    for _ in (1...f!){
        if(icon.isHittable){
            break
        }
        else{
            springboard.swipeLeft()
        }
    }


    let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion.prefix(2)

    switch systemVersion {
    case "13":
        icon.press(forDuration: 1)

        let rrd = springboard.buttons["Delete App"]
        XCTAssert(rrd.waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        rrd.tap()
        let rrd2 = springboard.buttons["Delete"]
        XCTAssert(rrd2.waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        rrd2.tap()
        
    case "14":
        icon.press(forDuration: 1)

        let rrd = springboard.buttons["Remove App"]
        XCTAssert(rrd.waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        rrd.tap()
        let rrd2 = springboard.buttons["Delete App"]
        XCTAssert(rrd2.waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        rrd2.tap()
        let rrd3 = springboard.buttons["Delete"]
        XCTAssert(rrd3.waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        rrd3.tap()
        
    default:
        XCTFail("Did not handle")
    }
   
}}
```