# I can't delete my application during the teardown phase of my tests

Tags: swiftui, swift5, xctest, xctestcase

I'm writing tests within my SwiftUI application and am working with `XCTest` and `XCTestCase`. Within my tests, I'm working with (and without) certain user permissions.

The problem that I am running into, is that once permission is set, I must delete the app or reset the settings of the simulator.

I'd like to automate this process within the tests themselves. I was referencing [Is there a way to reset the app between tests in Swift XCTest UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107731/is-there-a-way-to-reset-the-app-between-tests-in-swift-xctest-ui), but the solutions are written in Swift 4 and Swift 3, whereas I am working with Swift 5.

I've also tried [XCUITest Class teardown isnt deleting the app. But works if its instance teardown. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181823/xcuitest-class-teardown-isnt-deleting-the-app-but-works-if-its-instance-teardow) and can't seem to get that working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset application's permissions with Xcode 11.4 API
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/3526066-resetauthorizationstatus

---

If you still want to delete the app on iOS 13, check my answer here
[How to delete/reset an app from iOS 13 with XCTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509372/how-to-delete-reset-an-app-from-ios-13-with-xctest/58509930#58509930)